# Inconsistent Null Reference Exception when instantiate a Zombie

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I am using Unity version 5.6.1f1, if it helps.

At random moments when I instantiate a `Zombie` where it causes a `NullReferenceException` pointing to the `ThirdPersonController.cs`. However, this GameObject and script were built by Unity as their Standard Character Package Asset. All I did was attach by script, the `Zombie.target` to the `Player.transform` Some zombie's chase the `Player` as expected, but some don't.

This error has come up on the Unity forum and the only solutions found was to remove the FSM pointing to `ThirdPersonCharacter.CheckGroundStatus()`, or that the Animator was not assigned.

In the picture, the target set to "none" always targets the Player during game play. 
[image: Zombie Prefab][image: Zombie pic extended]

Error:

```
 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.ThirdPersonCharacter.CheckGroundStatus () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/ThirdPersonCharacter/Scripts/ThirdPersonCharacter.cs:215)
    UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.ThirdPersonCharacter.Move (Vector3 move, Boolean crouch, Boolean jump) (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/ThirdPersonCharacter/Scripts/ThirdPersonCharacter.cs:54)
    UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson.AICharacterControl.Update () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/ThirdPersonCharacter/Scripts/AICharacterControl.cs:39)
```

ThirdPersonCharacter, relevant section:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down, out hitInfo, m_GroundCheckDistance))
{
    m_GroundNormal = hitInfo.normal;
    m_IsGrounded = true;
    m_Animator.applyRootMotion = true; //ERROR HERE
}
```

Full script (Unity supplied asset):

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
    public class ThirdPersonCharacter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] float m_MovingTurnSpeed = 360;
        [SerializeField] float m_StationaryTurnSpeed = 180;
        [SerializeField] float m_JumpPower = 12f;
        [Range(1f, 4f)][SerializeField] float m_GravityMultiplier = 2f;
        [SerializeField] float m_RunCycleLegOffset = 0.2f; //specific to the character in sample assets, will need to be modified to work with others
        [SerializeField] float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
        [SerializeField] float m_AnimSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
        [SerializeField] float m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;

        Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
        Animator m_Animator;
        bool m_IsGrounded;
        float m_OrigGroundCheckDistance;
        const float k_Half = 0.5f;
        float m_TurnAmount;
        float m_ForwardAmount;
        Vector3 m_GroundNormal;
        float m_CapsuleHeight;
        Vector3 m_CapsuleCenter;
        CapsuleCollider m_Capsule;
        bool m_Crouching;


        void Start()
        {
            m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            m_Capsule = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
            m_CapsuleHeight = m_Capsule.height;
            m_CapsuleCenter = m_Capsule.center;

            m_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ;
            m_OrigGroundCheckDistance = m_GroundCheckDistance;


        void CheckGroundStatus()
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            // helper to visualise the ground check ray in the scene view
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f) + (Vector3.down * m_GroundCheckDistance));
#endif
            // 0.1f is a small offset to start the ray from inside the character
            // it is also good to note that the transform position in the sample assets is at the base of the character
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down, out hitInfo, m_GroundCheckDistance))
            {
                m_GroundNormal = hitInfo.normal;
                m_IsGrounded = true;
                m_Animator.applyRootMotion = true; //ERROR HERE
            }
            else
            {
                m_IsGrounded = false;
                m_GroundNormal = Vector3.up;
                m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AICharacterControl:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof (ThirdPersonCharacter))]
    public class AICharacterControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent agent { get; private set; }             // the navmesh agent required for the path finding
        public ThirdPersonCharacter character { get; private set; } // the character we are controlling
        public Transform target;                                // target to aim for
        private GameObject player; 

        private void Start()
        {
            // get the components on the object we need ( should not be null due to require component so no need to check )
            agent = GetComponentInChildren<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
            character = GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();

            player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
            target = player.transform;

            agent.updateRotation = false;
            agent.updatePosition = true;
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            if (target != null)
                agent.SetDestination(target.position);

            if (agent.remainingDistance > agent.stoppingDistance)
                character.Move(agent.desiredVelocity, false, false);
            else
                character.Move(Vector3.zero, false, false);
        }


        public void SetTarget(Transform target)
        {
            this.target = target;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Go to the console tab then double click on the error. It will take you to the line of code that is causing that error. Add edit to your question and post that line of code.

Comment: I increased the value of Check Ground Distance and Run Cycle Leg Offset from 2 to 10. It seems to have reduced the chances of the NullReference occuring; however, the NullReference still happens. I looked at the Profiler and the Game Engine performance is less than 15 FPS.

Comment: Also, the zombies go to my previous position rather than the Player's most recent position and it takes 30 seconds to realise that I have moved by 5meters. Any tips to increase the performance of Game Engine on Unity, which hopefully would reduce even more the chances of NullReferences from happening? [I have 8GB Ram, i7 CPU, Intel 4000 graphics card.]

Comment: I can't really discus about performance here because there are loads of stuff that can cause performance problems. It could scripts, shaders, bad model, HQ textures.....

Comment: It may be caused by the fact, that you are using `NavMeshAgent` as well as `ThirdPersonCharacter` to move your zombie. Choose one or the other.

Comment: Try to replace the void "Start" in the ThirdPersonCharacter.cs with "Awake". Helped me with a similiar problem

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "void Start" with "void Awake" in the ThirdPersonCharacter.cs.

I had a very similar problem when using the ThirdPersonCharacter.cs with another AI-behaviour script: worked fine in the editor, but as soon as I built it, I got the null reference exception, both in the build and in the editor. I couldn't really find anything on the web, null reference exception errors are very common, but mostly you solve them by fixing this for one variable... I'm a relative rookie with c#, but I think it's not a general problem with the script, but with the way the variables are called / initialized. Anyway, this worked for me.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html